# Getting Segmentation fault (core dumped) on C program

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

[image]

I have this problem in my main.c file, but I don't know the line or where the error is coming from.
Please if you can provide more tips for debuging my program or how I can found more about the error.
I dont't have strtol in my code

backtrace

```
#0  __GI_____strtol_l_internal (nptr=0x0, endptr=endptr@entry=0x0, base=base@entry=10, group=group@entry=0, loc=0x7ffff7a32560 <_nl_global_locale>) at ../stdlib/strtol_l.c:292
#1  0x00007ffff768b122 in __strtol (nptr=<optimized out>, endptr=endptr@entry=0x0, base=base@entry=10) at ../stdlib/strtol.c:106
#2  0x00007ffff7686690 in atoi (nptr=<optimized out>) at atoi.c:27
#3  0x00005555555553b7 in readFromFile ()
#4  0x0000555555554de0 in task1 ()
#5  0x0000555555554d4b in whatTaskToSolve ()
#6  0x0000555555554bbc in main ()
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy&paste from a shall is no magic.

Comment: I would guess you call `strtol` with some `NULL` pointer. Showing the backtrace (`bt`) might be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe at the line where `atoi(...)` is called? Check such lines.

Comment: I didn't use strtol in my code

Comment: Maybe atoi() function?

Answer (score 1):

Segmentation fault occurs due to misuse of pointers and arrays.Just check any array overflow, null pointer check, dangling pointers , wild pointers etc:- .

you can analyse codedump using gdb debugger and check on which line your are getting segmentation fault.Check this link http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2016-08-09/gdb-example-ncurses.html to know more about it.